# codeigniter / database page not loading

Tags: database, codeigniter, loading, pyrocms

I have a problem whith a database request : the webpage does not load at all.

```
    public function get_mylist($user_id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->_table);
        $this->db->where('my', '1');
        $this->db->where('user1', $user_id);
        $this->db->or_where('user2', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        if($query!=NULL)
        {
            foreach($query as $row)
            {
            echo $row['user1'];
                if($row['user2'] != $user_id)
                {
                    $data[] = $row['user2'];
                }
                else if($row['user1'] != $user_id)
                {
                    $data[] = $row['user1'];
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

edit : in my log i have Fatal error:  Allowed memory size bytes exhausted

So my loop must be wrong :/

Comment: i have this error in my log : Fatal error:  Allowed memory size bytes exhausted. I must have an error in my loop, if anyone can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider how many rows in your DB table and how many bytes per row.

Do you have enough data in your table to reach the memory limit for your PHP configuration?

Also, check your logic in your SQL construction.

Specifically:

```
 $this->db->where('my', '1');
 $this->db->where('user1', $user_id);
 $this->db->or_where('user2', $user_id);
```

This `where` clause is being interpreted as:

```
WHERE (`my` = 1 AND `user1` = $user_id) OR (`user2` = $user_id)
```

Is this what you intended, or do you need:

```
WHERE `my` = 1 AND (`user1` = $user_id OR `user2` = $user_id)
```

In MySQL, `OR` gets precedence over `AND`.

Finally, as a test, take out the code that parses the `$data` array and return the `$row` array and print it out using `print_r($row)` and make sure your query is pulling out the data that you expect.

Hopefully these ideas will help you diagnose the problem.  Best of luck!

**Note:** To implement the alternative logic in SQL, you may do something like:

```
 $this->db->where('my', '1');
 $this->db->where("(`user1` = $user_id OR `user2` = $user_id)");
```

Pay attention to the opening/closing parentheses immediately to the inside of the
double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. my sql table has 3 columns and 2 rows so I don't think the probelm comes from the memory. So I only have one row which returns user 1 and user 2 so I don't understand what is the matter. How can I achieve WHERE my = 1 AND (user1 = $user_id OR user2 = $user_id) ? should I put the where('my', '1') after the other conditions ?

Comment: After several test, i found that the problem comes from the "return". I can var_dump(data) and it shows an array but i cannot return it oO"

Comment: In your snippet, `$data` is an array, not an object.  However, you could define an object if that is what you prefer.  The memory error message may be due to trying to use an array as an object (?)

Comment: thank's a lot. I was indeed trying to use an object whereas it is an array.